# When row is edited in gridview the row becomes empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a datagridview when I click on edit I can modify the text but when I click on save the row becomes empty I don't understand why this is the case.

Here is what it looks when i click on edit
[image: Image of edit]

Here is a  image after I clicked on save.
[[image: save clicked[2]]

Here is the save code.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    TextBox txtID  = row.FindControl("txtID") as TextBox;
    TextBox txtName = row.FindControl("txtName") as TextBox;
    TextBox txtCity= row.FindControl("txtCity") as TextBox;

    foreach (Emp obj in lEmp)
    {
        if (obj.ID == int.Parse(txtID.Text))
        {
            obj.ID = int.Parse(txtID.Text);
            obj.Name = txtName.Text;
            obj.City = txtCity.Text;
            break;
        }
    }
    BindGridList("", "");
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: JS code might be useful here. Or are you using Web Forms?

Comment: I am using web forms and I would prefer to do it using web forms. As I am not very familiar with javascript.

Comment: Just tag web forms in this case. Because asp.net is a bit wider field ;)

Comment: Thank you for the advice I have added the tag.